# WebCT format description

Tags: text, moodle, file-format

I would like to have a reference on the WebCT format to import questions into Moodle.

https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Import_questions#WebCT_format

shows some examples but I would be interested in how to format essay questions.

The only other page I have found about WebCT was

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebCT

But that do not refer to the format, only the system.

Where can I find a reference to the WebCT text format?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pyzdrowski.ws/conference/ICTCM2003/webctquestionsweb.pdf

contains a good description of the textual format, especially

> Section Two. Creating a question using a text editor:

starting at page 5:

http://www.pyzdrowski.ws/conference/ICTCM2003/webctquestionsweb.pdf#page=5